# ISR vs main: what are the trade offs of running in one or the other?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, isr

I know it has to do with time and efficiency, and how ISRs take time away from other processes, but I am unclear why this is. I am always told to keep ISRs very short. I am a bit confused why this is.

Comment: What I'm confused about is what you call "main" in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, ISRs come into scene when a hardware device needs to interact with the CPU. They send an interrupt signal that makes the CPU to leave whatever it was doing to service the interrupt. That it's what ISR must care about.

Now, this depends on many factors, being the hardware environment and the nature of the interrupt maybe the most relevant ones, but it usually happens that in order to properly service an interrupt, ISRs run with interrupts disabled so they cannot be interrupted. This means that the CPU cannot be shared among other processes while it is running ISR code because the system timer interrupt that is used to run the scheduler (which is the part of the kernel that takes care of making the illusion that the CPU can do several tasks at the same time) won't work.

So, if your ISR takes too much time to perform a certain operation with the device, your system will be affected as a whole, because the percentage of time the CPU is available for the rest of processes will be less than usual. This is much noted on old system with PIO hard disks, which interrupt the CPU for every disk sector they want to transfer to the CPU, and the ISR must do the actual transfer. If there's many disk traffic, you may notice things like your mouse moving jerky (because the interrupt that the mouse device sends to the CPU is not attended)

OSes like Linux allow ISRs to defer time consuming operations with hardware devices to tasklets: sort of kernel threads that can share CPU time with other processes, yet keeping the atomic nature of hardware device operations (the OS ensures that there won't be more than one tasklet function -for the specific tasklet associated to the ISR- running in the system at the same time). The PIO transfer from disk to kernel buffers is an example of such operation.

Answer (score 1):

Some precisions w.r.t. the accepted answer.

Interrupts are not necessarily disabled when running an interrupt, and that is not necessarily the reason why the kernel processes all interrupts before returning to threads.

There is the concept of interrupt priorities. An interrupt of higher priority will preempt a running ISR: if the timer interrupt is of higher priority than the running ISR, *it will run*. However, a kernel will not handle context switches at this time, but rather defer them until all queued/pending ISRs have run.

Also, on some processors (eg. ARM Cortex-M3), the concept of handling an interrupt is a mode of operation in the processor itself. The processor cannot go back to running threads until it gets out of interrupt mode. Once that happens, all interrupts are fully serviced: you cannot go back to running an ISR.

But the main reason why all ISRs must finish before going back to threads is that kernels do not have the concept of a thread-like running context for ISRs. An ISR thus *cannot pend*: it must run to completion. An ISR is thus hogging the CPU, except from higher-priority interrupts, until it finishes its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the main thread has lower priority than the ISRs. Depending on the scheduler, often the main code will be executed after all pending ISRs have been run.

Having alot of computation intensive code in one or many ISR is generally not advisable, since it may cause delays or even CPU starvation of lower priority ISRs or threads, which may be detrimental if time-critical code needs to be executed.

However, when action needs to be taken immediately at an interrupt event, the fastest way is to execute code from the associated ISR (and possibly assign it a high priority).

If you plan on using several interrupt sources that execute time-consuming code, the way to go is by using an RTOS to allow safe and efficient interleaving of several threads to service each of the interrupts.